# How to avoid loading data from server every time doing sorting/paging with ngtable

Tags: angularjs, ajax, sorting, paging, ngtable

I am using ngtable (1.0.0) to display records fetched from server side. My controller js looks like this:

```
ristoreApp.controller("fmCtrl",
    ['$scope', '$filter', 'fmFactory', 'NgTableParams', function($scope, $filter, fmFactory, NgTableParams) {
        var self = this;
        $scope.selection = '0';
        $scope.fmSearch = function () {
            if ($scope.selection == '0') {
                self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10,          // count per page
                    sorting: {
                        frReportId: 'asc'
                    }
                }, {
                    getData: function (params) {
                        return fmFactory.getAll()
                            .then(function(response) {
                                var reports = response.data;
                                params.total(reports.length);
                                console.log(params.total());
                                var sorted = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(reports, params.orderBy()) : reports;
                                return sorted.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

HTML for the table:

```
<div ng-controller="fmCtrl as fm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row top-margin-80">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="keyword" placeholder="Enter MRN or report ID" />
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="filter">Search by</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="selection">
                                                <option value="0" selected>All Reports</option>
                                                <option value="1" >MRN</option>
                                                <option value="2">ReportID</option>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="optionword" ng-hide="selection == '0'"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fmSearch()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <table ng-table="fm.tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" show-filter="false">
            <tr ng-repeat="report in $data">
                <td data-title="'ReportId'" filter="{frReportId: 'text'}" sortable="'frReportId'" class="text-center">
                    {{report.frReportId}}</td>
                <td data-title="'BlockId'" filter="{frBlockId: 'text'}" sortable="'frBlockId'" class="text-center">
                    {{report.frBlockId}}</td>
                <td data-title="'MRN'" filter="{mrn: 'text'}" sortable="'mrn'" class="text-center">
                    {{report.mrn}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{frFullName: 'text'}" sortable="'frFullName'" class="text-center">
                    {{report.frFullName}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Diagnosis'" filter="{frDiagnosis: 'text'}" sortable="'frDiagnosis'" class="text-center">
                    {{report.frDiagnosis}}</td>
                <td data-title="'File'" class="text-center"><a ng-href="{{report.filepath}}">{{report.frReportId}}.xml</a>
                    </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works, well sort of. Problem is whenever I click on the titles to sort and page button to go to next page, it makes an ajax call to server to retrieve data again. I have over 2000 records in the database, every time I do something to the table, it takes 5 seconds to respond which is very annoying. How do I make it load the data only the first time and cache it on client side for future manipulation?

Comment: Where is your HTML?  It seems you are calling getData every time you click.  You only need to get the data once and save it in scope.  You can use lazy loading for pagination.  Can't really help without seeing all of your code.

Comment: Try to put your response.data into a $scope variable  $scope.reports = response.data then refer to it for pagination and sort, anyway i don't think that to sore 2000 records to client is a good idea...

Comment: store the data in a service, or cache the $http request as per docs. Be careful though with your strategy if data is likely to be changed by other users

Comment: @RaniRadcliff html added. `ng-click="fmSearch()` is only called when I click on the search button outside the table.

Comment: Sorry to add a question, but why `<tr ng-repeat="report in $data">` instead of `<tr ng-repeat="report in reports">`? isn't that what force the query?

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Not sure, I just followed the official examples on ng-table.com and they use `$data`

Comment: @Vermicello I did implement paging and sorting on the server side initially. But what the table shows are attributes from three different tables. So the sorting works on the few attributes that belong to the main entity but not for the attributes from joined entities. I had this other post for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379370/how-to-sort-entity-by-field-from-parent-entity-in-jpa-repository) which hasn't been answered. Another reason I decided to move paging to client is because if too many traffic, server may not be able to handle as some articles pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Solution is to move the ajax call `var Ajax = fmFactory.getAll();` outside ngtable constructor.

```
                var Ajax = fmFactory.getAll();
                self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10,          // count per page
                    sorting: {
                        frReportId: 'asc'
                    }
                }, {
                    getData: function (params) {
                        return Ajax.then(function(response) {
                                var reports = response.data;
                                params.total(reports.length);
                                console.log(params.total());
                                var sorted = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(reports, params.orderBy()) : reports;
                                return sorted.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                        });
                    }
                });
```